# Printing CFLAGS in GNU make exaclty once if source files have changed

Tags: gnu-make

Here is a snippet from my makefile:

```
all: $(TARGET) 

$(C_OBJS): %.o: %.c
    @ echo -n "Compiling " $*.c;
    @ $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $*.o
    @ echo " ...... Done"

$(TARGET): $(C_OBJS)
    @ $(AR) rus $@ $(C_OBJS);

print_cflags:
    @ echo "CFLAGS: " $(CFLAGS) "\n"
```

Moving forward, I want to

1. Print the `CFLAGS` **once** if compilation takes place.
2. Get `make: Nothing to be done for "all"` message if no modifications has been done from previous build. Printing `CFLAGS` is optional in this case.

I feel, it can be achieved by keeping a counter inside `$(C_OBJS): %.o: %.c`But is there any better way to achieve this?
I understand that this is a very specific question but any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add `print_cflags` as an `order-only` prerequisite to the `$(TARGET)` rule?

Comment: @EtanReisner Thanks for your comment but by adding `print_cflags` as an `order-only` prerequisite the `make: Nothing to be done for "all"` message is suppressed.

Comment: Hm... ok. You could always stop using a make target for that and stick the print in the `$(TARGET)` rule body itself.

Comment: This is a feasible option but the whole build process in my case takes around 20 minutes to complete. So I would like to see the prints before compilation starts.

Comment: Add `@touch $@` to the rules for `print_cflags`, add `print_cflags` as a prerequisite (order-only would be best I think) of the `$(COBJS)` static pattern rule and then mark `print_cflags` as `.INTERMEDIATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Etan gives a number of good options.  Here's another one, assuming your version of GNU  make is new enough to support `eval`:

```
print_CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS)

$(C_OBJS): %.o: %.c
        @ $(if $(print_CFLAGS),echo "CFLAGS: $(print_CFLAGS)" $(eval print_CFLAGS:=))
        @ echo -n "Compiling " $*.c;
        @ $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c -o $*.o
        @ echo " ...... Done"
```